# Configuring custom retry topic in spring-kafka 2.8

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Trying to customize the topic name for retry. While running getting circualar reference error. What could be the reason?
**Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?**

```
@bean
public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory myRetryNamingProviderFactory() {
    return new CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory();
}

 @KafkaListener(topics = "${application.kafka.topic-incoming}", groupId = "${application.kafka.consumer-group-id}",id = "2", concurrency = "1")
 @RetryableTopic(attempts = "1", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1_000, maxDelay = 10_000, multiplier = 2), autoCreateTopics = "false")
public void listenRequest(@Payload @Valid HelloRequest message) {
        log.info("Message recieved :: {} on {}", messages.toString(), topics);
        if (messages.getName().equals("Failed")) {
            log.info("Throwing Error");
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        }
     
    }


public class CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {

        if (properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties);
        } else {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {
                @Override
                public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                    return  super.getTopicName(topic)+"-na1995";
                }

            };
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory from @Bean  to @Component and it worked.

```
@Component
public class CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {

        if (properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties);
        } else {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {
                @Override
                public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                    return  super.getTopicName(topic)+"-na1995";
                }

            };
        }
    }

}
```